# Unit test cases are not getting executed in python

Tags: python

```
import unittest


class TestCaseDemo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print('setUP')

    def any_test(self):
        print('test')

    def tearDown(self):
        print('tearDown')


unittest.main()
```

Output:

---

Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Those are *functions*, not methods in the class.

Comment: I'm probably seeing the same problem @jonrsharpe has pointed out. Are you sure you have indented everything properly?

Comment: Like @JST99 and @jonrsharpe pointed out, your "tests" are not in the `TestCaseDemo` class. Just adjust your indentation.

Comment: JST99  and @jonrsharpe  and Noah Broyles idenation is correct , I have also debug the code , its just not entering into the functions

Comment: It would help if you copied your code in so it displayed correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue (aside from indentation) is that your test function doesn't start with `test`.  Using the [unittest (docs)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html) module requires that naming.

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def this_is_not_a_test(self):
       print("doesn't start with 'test'")
```

From the "Basic Example" [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html#basic-example):

> A testcase is created by subclassing unittest.TestCase. The three individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters `test`. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.

Comment: Thank you it worked , I think test keyword is necessary